# Magic for undefined function?

Tags: php, function, magic-methods

Is there such a thing?

Some kind of a magic function that allows you to change stuff before the undefined function call error gets thrown?

Like [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), but for normal functions :)

Comment: Maybe you could describe why would you want this behaviour? I haven't encountered such need ever...

Comment: No such thing, I believe. No [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=25&catname=PHP) specifically, which is what you would need.

Comment: Why catch an error instead of preventing it? Just tests if the function exists with [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the cheking BEFORE calling the method like this:

```
$obj = new Foo();
$method = "myMethod";

if(is_callable(array($obj, $method)){
    $obj->$method();
}else{
    // Do some stuff
}
```